# JSF 2.0 : Multiple ajax responses for a request

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I will be having a data table where multiple selections (check boxes) can be done. I should fire a **single AJAX request** in return I should be able to **update the status of each selection** (rows) in ***multiple AJAX responses***.

How can I achieve this in JSF 2.0? I have reviewed **PrimeFaces, ICEFaces and RichFaces**, but I couldn't come to a conclusion of which one to use to accomplish this requirement. 
I'm new JSF 2.0, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you need multiple ajax responses? How exactly is a single ajax response with all rows (basically, the entire table) insufficient?

Comment: @BalusC Each ajax response is for each selection in the data table. Each selection represents (a device) will have the status which should be updated on event basis. The client don't want any compromise on it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. I only don't understand why exactly a single ajax response (as done by the standard JSF JS API works) is insufficient for you.

Comment: @BalusC My problem is how would i achieve the status changes for each selection in a single response. The status flags have two phases. Until the process gets completed, I should display the progress of status for each selection.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. I only don't understand why exactly a single ajax response (as done by the standard JSF JS API works) is insufficient for you. Why does it *need* to be returned in multiple responses instead of in a single response?

Answer (score 0):

If you know ids of all the fields need to be update then this can be done like this

```
List<String> renderList = (List<String>)        
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds();

renderList.add(clientId1);
renderList.add(clientId2);
renderList.add(clientId3);
renderList.add(clientId4);
```

here client id is compbination of id and form id eg:

```
<h:form id="myBean">
    <h:inputText id="textBox" />
</h:form>
```

then client id will be :    myBean:textBox

then all the fields you are adding in re-renderlist will be rerender in single ajax request

Comment: This is normally to be specified in `<f:ajax render>`. E.g. `<f:ajax render="id1 id2 id3" />`.

Comment: @BalusC : yes but the only difference is in xhtml inside the f:ajax tag it is fix and in java you can do it dynamically, different render for different condition/state for same ajax request